# Sharepoint item permissions "created by" need multiple entries

Tags: sharepoint, permissions

I have a sales opportunities list and only want the "Account Owner" and "Account Team" to be able to edit Items in the list, everyone else can view.
In "Advanced Settings" I have "Read Access" set to "All Items" and I have "Edit Access" set to "Only their own"

Issue 1: I imported the list items so the "created by" column that SP looks at for permissions has my name on every item so I am the only one who can edit items

Issue 2: I need people listed in the "Account Team" people picker column to also be able to edit the list item

Issue 3: I can't filter the "Account Team" column by member as it does not allow "contains"

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

So should users only be able to edit their own items or members of the Account Owner and Account Team groups can edit any item in the list?

If it's the latter then set the Edit Access to any item. Then set the permissions on the list so that those two groups can contribute and a group encompassing all users can read/view.

Comment: I want it so that if the logged in users name appears in the "Account Owner" or "Account Team" columns that person can view and edit that item, but only view any other item without their user name in those columns.

Comment: Well, as sparkymark75 said, you need to set Edit Access to any item. Then you must have event receiver attached to item which, on ItemAdded and ItemUpdated events updates those permissions (you check which users have been removed from your columns - remove permissions for them and for those that are added, you add permissions)

Comment: In our farm, we have Nintex Workflow, which has an Edit Item Permissions activity that works like a charm in this scenario. I don't know if SPD has a comparable activity that you could use without writing code. You might consider checking it out.

Comment: For SharePoint 2007 there are custom activities on CodePlex (http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) that can handle permissions. SharePoint 2010 has similar activities out of the box.